# Why has the notification "Disk not ejected properly" changed in Mojave?

Tags: hard-drive, mojave, notifications, settings, eject

Whenever my iMac wakes from sleep I find 'hundreds' of  "Disk not ejected properly" notifications.This has only started since an upgrade to Mojave.
Is there an obscure setting that I can change to avoid this annoyance?